# How do you divide each element in a 2-dimensional array by a value? (python)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Basic python question -- I have a 296x296 sized array and I would like to divide each value in the array by 10. Is there a method in numpy to do this? I am thinking np.divide but I can't seem to to divide an array by a single float value. Thanks

Comment: You simply divide the array by 10. And you will get the desired result. No need to use any method for this.

Comment: `y = x/10` should do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
X = np.random.random((296,296))
X = X / 10.
# or
X =/ 10. # operation is conducted in-place
# or
Y = np.divide(X,10.)
# or 
X = np.divide(X,10.) # equivalent to X = X / 10.
np.divide(X,10., out = X) # equivalent to X /= 10.
```